# Вывод многомерного массива с ключами

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Есть многомерный массив aqua, который я вывожу через foreach

Сам массив (вывел через var_export)

```html
array ( 6 => array ( 'quantity' => '1', 'price' => '189', ), 3 => array ( 'quantity' => '101', 'price' => '278', ), )
```

Моим кодом

```html
foreach ($aqua['cart'] as $value) {
     foreach($aqua['cart']  as  $inner_key => $value2){
    echo $value['quantity'] . " | " . $value['price'] . "|" . $inner_key .  '<br>';
  }
 }
```

Выводит это:

```html
1 | 189|6
1 | 189|3
101 | 278|6
101 | 278|3
```

И это, в принципе, логично, потому что у меня такой запрос и цикл два раза повторяется. Проблема в том, что я не понимаю, как его переписать так, чтобы мне выводилось только один раз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что надо так

```
foreach ($aqua['cart'] as $key=>$value) {
    echo $value['quantity'] . " | " . $value['price'] . "|" . $key .  '<br>';
 }
```